# Definition of model in the tag excerpt: random relationship(s) between variables

Tags: terminology, model, randomness

The tag excerpt of [model](/questions/tagged/model) says:

> A formalization of relationships between stochastically (randomly) related variables in the form of mathematical equations.

This seems questionable to me. I guess cases where this holds exist, but what about the majority of the relatively simple cases? The basic models often have deterministic relationships between variables; e.g. in a linear model,
$$
Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 X+\varepsilon.
$$
$Y$ and $\varepsilon$ are random variables, $X$ may be random or nonrandom, so there are objects that are random. However, the relationship between these objects (here in the form of the linear model) is fixed. Does it make sense to say variables are stochastically (randomly) related here?

Comment: You could also object that $Y$ and $X$ are deterministic in most applied settings...

Comment: Not sure I understand. I wrote explicitly the opposite in my last paragraph. @Xi'an

Comment: Yes, I understand what you wrote but a similar objection could be made on the opposite basis.

Comment: Then I probably misunderstood you. Are you saying that one could make the case that $Y$ and $X$ are deterministic rather than stochastic? And if this were technically possible, would this not go against most of what statisticians do? To clarify, I am focusing on the tag excerpt in the particular context of statistics and Cross Validated.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are hinting at what a subjective Bayesian would think? I had forgotten that perspective when writing the question. Then the parameters become random variables while $Y$ and $X$ (and $\varepsilon$?) become fixed. But the model is still fixed, and we have *almost* a mirror image of what we had in the frequentist (or objective Bayesian - perhaps with caveats) interpretation, so I guess the question still applies.

Comment: In this post, I don't see any counterexamples to the characterization.  Any deterministic value can always be viewed as a degenerate version of a random variable, so every non-stochastic (quantitative) model can be viewed as a special case of this definition.  Moreover, your question hinges on changing the meaning of "related" to exclude the effect of $\varepsilon$ in the linear model.

Comment: @whuber, your first point is technically correct but I wonder if it is helpful. Calling an object stochastic when it is typically deterministic invites one to expect the wrong thing. An expression "stochastic or deterministic" makes sense, since one can contrast the two. Regarding the second point, I wonder if I understand you correctly. I think your point hinges on omitting $\varepsilon$ form consideration, as otherwise I do not see what is stochastic about the relationship $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\varepsilon$ between variables $Y$, $X$ and $\varepsilon$. If I got that right, I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

The definition is far too narrow. To identify a model in terms of random variables is to put noise on a pedestal AND reduce all modelling to one set of applications. Not all systems are stochastic, for example, the equations that model the position of a swinging pendulum may have some small noise of regression fit for  their application to any particular problem, but those equations are largely deterministic, and the "noise" may be one part in one million as a residual function. Worse, one man's noise for a deterministic model may be another man's data for a more exact model. Suppose on a hot day someone puts an oscillatory fan blowing air in the same room as an exposed pendulum. Then, the "noise," i.e., the residuals of fit, that result from timed positional data for the pendulum may themselves be largely deterministic and subject to secondary deterministic modelling.

Or try another typical measurement problem, [how long is a day](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/earth-rotation.html)?

Exact Day Length* — Sun, May 23, 2021

Today's prediction: 24 hours, 0 minutes, 0.0007688 seconds (0.7688 milliseconds)

The simple answer is 24 hours plus "noise." However, as above, the noise is predictable and the problem is deterministic to within a ridiculously small error. That is modelling at its best. Thus, to define what a model is and ignore the physical world (literally) is *disciplinary myopia* to coin a phrase.

To wit, I propose to say that a model is "The mathematical equation(s) formalizing the relationship(s) between variables."

Comment: Thank you for your perspective.

Comment: @RichardHardy Actually, thank you for your question. Things like [statistical mechanics](https://www.britannica.com/science/statistical-mechanics) provide some of the most elegant statistical models. Indeed, something to be proud of.